# cmake give me ECMFindQmlModule when complileing plasma-bigscreen

Tags: kde, 21.10, cmake

This is the output.
Note, I do have `extra-cmake-modules` installed.
ubuntu 21.10 rpi 4

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    ECMFindQmlModule


Installing in /usr/local. Run /home/lnee/Downloads/plasma-bigscreen-master/build/prefix.sh to set the environment for plasma-big-launcher.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:50 (ecm_find_qmlmodule):
  Unknown CMake command "ecm_find_qmlmodule".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lnee/Downloads/plasma-bigscreen-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2):

To compile and install [Plasma Bigscreen](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-bigscreen) on Ubuntu 21.10 one can follow [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=plasma-bigscreen-git) with `extra-cmake-modules` from git as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autopurge extra-cmake-modules
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libkf5activities-dev \
libkf5activitiesstats-dev libkf5plasma-dev kirigami2-dev libkf5declarative-dev \
libkf5kcmutils-dev libkf5notifications-dev libkf5kio-dev libkf5wayland-dev \
plasma-workspace-dev qtmultimedia5-dev appstream qtbase5-dev qtchooser \
qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qttools5-dev 'python3-sphinxcontrib*'

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/extra-cmake-modules
cd extra-cmake-modules
cmake .
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-bigscreen.git
cd plasma-bigscreen
cmake .
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Comment: Will this show up as a desktop environment?

Comment: I'm not sure, I compiled it inside Docker container without Xorg.  You have to check the README at its repository and maybe *documentation* folder there.

Comment: Ok I tested it shows in gdm but not sddm and when i tried launching it was just a mouse curcer

Comment: Black background + cursor : Suggest a couple of apps in `.config/autostart/`, e.g. firefox.desktop and a terminal.desktop, or whatever you want for the "bigscreen". ..... Opens OK here.

Comment: When I open the terminal in that state, it opens and run fine but when I run plasma-bigscreen-x11 a window opens it says plasma-bigscreen is already open